# Телеграм бот, создание папок os.makedirs()

Tags: python, бот, python-telegram-bot, telegram

Создаю телеграмм бота на python(python-telegram-bot = 13.6)Возникла проблема после заливания на хостинг. Метод os.makedirs(), который принимает значения context.user_data перестал работать. Принимает только строки. Что можно придумать? Пробовал использовать pathlib, но ошибка такая же. ОС Ubuntu 18.04. Есть основная папа "info" в ней расположены папки с названиями специальностей. И в этих папках уже создается папка пользователя. К примеру: info/Программист/Иванов Иван Иванович.

```
context.user_data[SURNAME] = first_name
    context.user_data[NAME] = surname
    context.user_data[LASTNAME] = last_name
    p = Path(context.user_data[SURNAME])
    p.mkdir(parents = True)
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id = update.message.chat.id,  
        text = "Укажите ваш пол",
        reply_markup = select_male 
)
```

Comment: Приведите в вопрос ОС на хостинге и на локальной машине где все работает, так же было бы неплохо привести структуру проекта (папки)

Comment: Спасибо, дополнил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

dpath = '/opt/tlgrm_bot/'

# Создать папку название которой будет содержать id пользователя по пути /opt/tlgrm_bot/user_data/%id пользователя%/
Path(dpath + 'user_data/{}'.format(message.chat.id)).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 

# Если тип сообщения фото, сохранить изображение по пути /opt/tlgrm_bot/user_data/%id пользователя%/
if message.content_type == 'photo':
            file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
            downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
            src = dpath + 'user_data/{}/'.format(message.chat.id) + file_info.file_path
            with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
                new_file.write(downloaded_file)
```

Comment: К сожалению оно не помогло, но я понял, что проблема точно в "context.user_data". Он не воспринимает его как строку и не создает папку. `context.user_data[SURNAME] = first_name
        context.user_data[NAME] = surname
        context.user_data[LASTNAME] = last_name

        dpath = 'info/'
        Path(dpath + '{}'.format(context.user_data[SURNAME])).mkdir(parents = True, exist_ok= True)
        context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id = update.message.chat.id,  
            text = "Укажите ваш пол",
            reply_markup = select_male 
    )`

Comment: Тогда явно укажите что это строка с помощью `str()`

Comment: Я смог решить проблему, дело было в версии python 3.6. Сменил ОС Ubuntu на 21 и все заработало!